# How to display many elements on the same line using script shell?

Tags: shell

I have an array of elements and I want to display all the elements of the array on the same line:

```
i=0
while read line
do 
    array[$i]= echo $line | tr '[A-Z]' '.'
    ((i+=1))
done

k=0
while [ $k -lt $i ]
do

    printf '%s '  ${array[$k]}
    ((k+=1))
done
```

the result of this program give me each element on a newline.How can I get all the elements on the same line separated by space?

Comment: Are you honestly using [tag:csh]? What you have looks more or less like bash.

Comment: Your second `while` loop would be find if the first loop actually populated the array correctly. The output you are seeing comes from the first loop, not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use `tr` for everything.

```
tr A-Z . | tr '\n' ' '
```

Reading the lines into an array makes no sense at all if you are not reordering the array.

Notice also how `tr` doesn't read a regular expression argument, just two lists of character ranges.

If you want to preserve the last line feed, restore it with a pipe to `sed`:

```
... | sed 's/ $/\n/'
```

(The notation to include a line feed in a `sed` script isn't entirely portable, but I believe this should work on any reasonably modern platform.)

These basic pipelines should work in any shell. Yours doesn't look like a `csh` script at all. The `printf` should have worked as such, but you were not initializing the array properly (and if it was, the loop would be superfluous).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can populate your array in two lines and no external commands:

```
readarray -t array
array=("${array[@]//[A-Z]/.}")
```

In earlier versions of `bash`, you'll still need the loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  array+=( "${line//[A-Z]/.}" )
done
```

In either case, you can then print the elements of the array on one line with

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}"
```